# Correct Japanese spelling of ‘Redemption’ when being used as a name for a male

Tags: meaning, translation, names

I am trying to find how to spell ‘Redemption’ in Japanese if I were going to use it as a name/alias.

Or if there is a wording/phrasing that means ‘Man on the path of Redemption’

Like yamabusi for warrior monk kind of thing

Comment: This thread has been closed for appropriate site-guideline reasons.  That said, I'd like to point out that there is no spelling for "redemption" in Japanese, as this is not a word in Japanese.  The question is a bit like asking, "how do you spell 「志す」 in English" -- you don't, because 「志す」 is not a word in English.

Comment: Ok well I just wanted a bit of language help. My apologies  and my question I suppose more related to the pronunciation as I believe the word would be Saido or perhaps Shokan but I’ll assume I’m going to be lambasted for not being grammatically perfect in outlining the possible correct word

Comment: No worries!  We all start somewhere.    I didn't understand that you wanted the translated Japanese word.  We get questions with varying degrees of language awareness, and it's not always clear what folks are looking for.  FWIW, _shōkan_ (償還) is more about "redemption, in monetary terms" -- like when someone "redeems" a loan, or a voucher, that kind of thing.  "Redemption" in terms of "atonement" or "personal salvation" would be _saido_ (済度). If we look at the Japanese Names Dictionary (ENAMDIC) mirror at Monash University, we see that "Saido" with this same kanji spelling is a placename...

Comment: ... but not a given name or surname: http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?2MUJsaido, note the code "p" which is explained http://nihongo.monash.edu/wwwjdicinf.html#code_tag if you scroll down to the "Names Dictionary Codes" section, where "p" = "place-name". That said, "Saido" is no that same list with other kanji spellings marked as "s" = "surname", so you could call a character 済度さん (_Saido-san_), and the _-san_ suffix makes it clear that you're using 済度 (_saido_) as a name, even though this spelling isn't apparently ever used as a real-world name.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow thank you very much eirikr that really was very helpful! Much appreciated and I will endeavour to be more specific/grammatically correct Ob my questions in future. Thanks again